# Convert List to Two Dimensional String array in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

My hibernate select query written the below list

```
[{SBI_ID=37889, MPN=EDFGHJK, VPN=GJHJKJK, Qty=567},
 {SBI_ID=2344, MPN=fdfdfd, VPN=werwr, Qty=34},
 {SBI_ID=53432, MPN=ererf, VPN=Sdcfv, Qty=567},
 {SBI_ID=37889, MPN=EDFGHJK, VPN=GJHJKJK, Qty=567}]
```

How to convert this List to the String[][] result ??

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: In addition to the above comment, please show the query you ran, and maybe tell us the types of all the columns.  It isn't clear why you would want to convert your result set into a 2D array of strings, given that some of the values seem to be numbers.

Comment: Why a 2d array, why not an array of custom class containing the values?

Comment: What you've posted looks like the output of `toString()` - what does the actual list look like?

Comment: I want to convert to 2d String array because I need to pass this list to a method that accepts only String[][]

Comment: `final String[][] result = thingList.stream().map(thing ->
                                   new String[] {Integer.toString(thing.sbi_id), thing.mpn, thing.vpn, Integer.toString(thing.qty)})
            .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new String[0][0]);`